# Change enemy sprite sheet when player in view c#

Tags: c#, sprite-sheet

This is related to the last question I asked, while the audio problem has been fixed, I'm still having trouble changing the sprite sheets for my enemies.

What's supposed to happen is that when the enemy gets in range of the player, their sprite sheet will change from a 'neutral' looking to 'hostile', I have some code so far -which I'll post- but I'm not sure where to go from where I am. The actual function to change the sprite sheet is within a timer, while the function is within the 'enemy' class.

I've declared and set the image in the actual enemy class, not the form, if that makes any difference.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
   public void ChangeSpriteSheet()
    {
        if (Hostile)
        {
            enemySprite = Properties.Resources.WormSheet; //'Hostile' sprite sheet
            CurrentPosition.seen = true;
        }
        else
        {
            enemySprite = Properties.Resources.WormSheetNeutral;

        }
    }
```

And the timer:

```
  //The timer to generate random numbers, is slower so that the enemy can complete it's move before picking a new direction
    private void wander_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentPosition.seen = false;
        int count = 0;

        foreach (Enemies en in enemyList)
        {
            en.ChangeSpriteSheet(); //Changes the sprite sheet of the enemy

            en.Direction(); //Determines the direction of the enemy when wandering
            count++;
        }

        //This foreach loop will play audio when any of the enemies sees the player
            if (CurrentPosition.seen)
            {
                wplayer.controls.play();//Plays music when player is in view
            }
            else
            {
                wplayer.controls.stop();//Stops the music
            }         
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, as always :)

Comment: Shouldn't things like this be driven from your main game loop? I haven't done a lot of game coding but I know I wouldn't be using a windows or system timer for this purpose. How is the `Hostile` flag set?

Comment: I didn't want it in my master timer, since that would effect the speed of my player sprite, so I put in a separate, slower timer for the enemies. I wouldn't know how to do it any other way :( And the hostile is set to true when the enemy gets within range of the player, and false when it isn't. Should I post the detection code?